# Continue execution of the code after alert message from clientside

Tags: c#, javascript

I've to send mail using webappplication.All works fine but i've to show a confirm message if attachments are not selected.In that confirm box when ok is clicked execution of the code should continue,when cancel button is clicked it should return.

This is my code

Code behind

```
 protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
string str = "Are you sure, you want to proceed without attachment?";  
this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Popup", "ConfirmApproval('" + str + "');", true);
...Send mail code goes here
}
```

ASPX

```
function ConfirmApproval(objMsg)
{
    if(confirm(objMsg))
    {
        alert("execute code.");
        return true;
    }    
    else
        return false;    
}
```

It works fine, ie when ok button is clicked an alert "execute code" is displaying.Instead of displaying alert i want to continue execution of the code.How will we do that from client side ???

Answer (score 1):

try this code,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnSend.Attributes.Add("onclick","return confirm('execute code');");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `confirm("execute code")` instead of 'alert'. Hope that helps :)

```
var agreed = confirm("execute code");

if(agreed) {
    //do something
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am showing you one brute force way to do that.

put that code behind in the page_load(sender, e) of any web page you create. Now call it through XHR.

(this may be a bad reply).